# Get FaceBook Friends List error code = 100 "Invalid username. field"

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, parse-platform

I am using PARSE integration for facebook. I am able to successfully link the user to facebook but when i try to get facebook firiends list i get the following error.

FBRequest *request = [FBRequest requestForMyFriends];

```
// Send request to Facebook
    [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error)
     {

     }];
```

error code = 100

message = "(#100) Unknown fields: username."

type = OAuthException

desperately need help!!

Answer (score 1):

The field `username` is no longer available with the Graph API v2.0, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_graph_api

> **Endpoints no longer available in v2.0**:
>
> ... 
>   /me/username is no longer available.

Comment: so apparently with the new facebook sdk changes you can no longer have a complete friends list. Only those friends are populated who are using the app. The error still didn't go away so i used FBRequest *request = [FBRequest requestWithGraphPath:@"me/friends" parameters:nil HTTPMethod:@"GET"]; and it worked

Comment: I don't really understand, your question was regarding a specific error. And that's what my answer was about.

Comment: I wanted to get the list of my friends to send the app invite. By using the requestWithGraphPath method i didn't get any data. So i had one of my friends to install the app who was in my friends list and then ran the requestWithGraphPath method which returned my friend's information suggesting that you can only have those friends in your friend list who are already using your application.

Comment: Still not related to your question. That is another topic.

Comment: Is there any way we can get our own facebook friendslist?

Answer (score 0):

```
-(IBAction)btnFacebookClick:(id)sender
{
    NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:                            @"user_about_me,user_birthday,user_hometown,user_location,email",@"read_mailbox",@"read_stream",nil];


    [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:permissions allowLoginUI:YES completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,FBSessionState status,NSError *error)
     {
         if(error)
         {
             NSLog(@"session error %@",error);

         }
         else if(FB_ISSESSIONOPENWITHSTATE(status))
         {


             [self getFriendList];
         }

     }];
}




-(void)getFriendList
{

    FBRequest *friendsRequest=[FBRequest requestForMyFriends];


    [friendsRequest startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,NSDictionary* result,NSError *error)
     {
         friendsArr = [result objectForKey:@"data"];

         NSLog(@"friends description :%@",[friendsArr description]);

     }];
}
```